# How to update using inner join for multiple column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting error 00933. 00000 -  `"SQL command not properly ended"`

```
UPDATE users SET                  
          username     = a.username,                  
          groupcode    = a.groupcode,             
          adauth       = a.adauth,               
          userlevel    = a.userlevel,                
          locationcd   = a.locationcd,            
          panno        = a.panno,                
          authrej      = a.authrej,                  
          multilogin   = a.multilogin,                 
          loginstatus  = a.loginstatus,                
          userstatus   = a.userstatus,                
          lupdnuser    = a.lupdnuser,                
          lupdndt      = a.lupdndt,                 
          createdby    = p_cUserId  ,                  
          createddt    = SYSTIMESTAMP,                
          closedby     = a.closedby ,                 
          closeddt     = a.closeddt ,                 
          emailid      = a.emailid  ,      
          passwordattempt =  CASE  cast ( a.userstatus as varchar)  WHEN '01' THEN  0  ELSE a.passwordattempt END                    
          FROM   userstrans a                      
          INNER  JOIN users b ON                    
          a.userid    = b.userid         
          AND a.sysuserno   =  b.sysuserno                         
          WHERE  a.systrnno     = p_nSysTrnNo                 
          AND   a.trnmode      = 'EDIT'                  
         AND   a.trnid        = 'N';
```

Comment: Update Statement with inner join will not support in oracle. Even from clause also. So use merge.

Comment: You can not use UPDATE this way; have a look at [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: @Buddi - that is not true. Oracle **does** support UPDATE with inner join - it just has to be done correctly. I don't understand why there are so many people who think Oracle does not support UPDATE with joins (and, worse, feel it OK to share their incorrect knowledge with the world). Please refrain from repeating that.

Comment: To the fool who voted to close this question: How is this due to a typo and/or how can it no longer be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this kind of updates is with the MERGE statement, as Aleksej suggested in a comment. MERGE is really easy to learn and use (especially if you are already familiar with UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE), it is very flexible, and sometimes more efficient (in execution) than UPDATE.

Alternatively, you can rewrite your UPDATE with JOIN to obey proper Oracle syntax. Both MERGE and UPDATE/JOIN assume the join condition (match condition for MERGE) identifies a unique row in the source table for each row in the target table; this is not a limitation (as some may think) but a logical requirement for the update to make sense in the first place.

The UPDATE with JOIN should look like this:

```
update 
  ( select b.username  as b_username , a.username  as a_username ,
           b.groupcode as b_groupcode, a.groupcode as a_groupcode,
           ETC.
    from   users b inner join userstrans a on b.userid    = a.userid 
                                          and b.sysuserno = a.sysuserno )
set b_username = a_username,   ETC.
where   <WHERE conditions here>
;
```

Compare the MERGE solution to this UPDATE with JOIN solution - you will appreciate how much clearer MERGE is!